# Using GDAL to ID a pair of GeoTiff Coordinates

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I've got a large library of images with no spatial reference. When I view the GeoTiff properties, I can view a lat/long under a "GPS" heading, but there's no indication of a coordinate system/projection.

My goal here is to identify a coordinate system and some coordinates in the image so that it can be georectified.

I've tried using GDALinfo to pull data, but it's giving everything to me in terms of pixels, not coordinates. GDALinfo also isn't outputting any coordinate system information.

Any ideas?

Also tried this code I found online and found "none".

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
ds = gdal.Open(r'SOMERASTER.TIF')
prj = ds.GetProjection()
print prj

srs = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)
if srs.IsProjected:
    print srs.GetAttrValue('projcs')
    print srs.GetAttrValue('geogcs')
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3x0jjq7ytu964c6/IMG_0019_1.tif?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide a sample image?

Comment: Unfortunately, the GeoTiff is too large to upload

Comment: You can make it smaller for sure and upload to Dropbox or somewhere. Just take care to keep the metadata, 2 x 2 pixels is big enough for the image data.

Comment: Uploaded to Dropbox, only 2-3mb.